# Каким образом сохраняются объекты в Clipboard'е?

Tags: windows, winapi, clipboard, memory-management

Каким образом сохраняются объекты в clipboard'e? Допустим некоторое изображение было создано при помощи `GlobalAlloc`, данная команда зарезервирует и будет использовать память в куче процесса (я имею ввиду 32-разрядную систему windows). Каким образом данный объект сохраняется в клипбоарде? в документации сказано что система после успешного завершения функции `SetClipboardData`завладеет объектом. (после завершения процесса изображение все равно будет храниться в буфере обмена). Более того, непонятно каким образом данное изображение может быть доступно остальным процессам, которые захотят скопировать его себе. Изображение перемещается в какой-то другой участок памяти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопроc! Памятью всегда владеет процесс.

Можно предположить, что API передает этот маркер `HGLOBAL` между активными процессами, которые подгрузили `User32.dll`.

т.е., перед выгрузкой из приложения `User32.dll`, подсистема "буфера обмена" копирует (а скорее всего - перемещает) буфер любому другому процессу, который подключил `User32.dll`.

Физическую страницу, в которой хранятся данные можно отобразить в любое адресное пространство, поэтому нет необходимости явно копировать данные между процессами, но это уже скорее всего специфика менеджера памяти. Возможно где-то есть статья "HGLOBAL from the inside", чтобы пролить свет на этот вопрос, но даже если нет - это можно сделать как минимум через [AWE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366527(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Интересное предположение.